# Cakephp Search Plugin from CakeDC

Tags: search, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Has anyone incorporated the [Seach plugin from CakeDC](http://github.com/CakeDC/search)?

I am a confused as in how it has to be used. I am creating a Seach Controller and trying to search all models from there.

In the Wiki, it states that I should create a `$filterArgs` variable on my models. Should I have public `$filterArgs` in every model or should only at one place?

If there is a tutorial can someone point me to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be in each model.  The controller, which generally uses only one model, then uses it.  I've had nothing but trouble trying to make one controller handle multiple models, apart from using one model and related data.